# Angular 6 : Observable<string[]> and isEmpty() operator

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this code :

```
asList: BehaviorSubject<string[]> = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>([]);    
this.list$ = this.asList.asObservable();
this.empty$ = this.list$.pipe(isEmpty());
```

but in template :

```
{{empty$ | async}}
```

always prints 'false', even when asList has items in it.

What am I doing wrong ?

Edit :

```
import { map, isEmpty } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: propably `isEmpty` function returns a boolean value

Comment: `pipe` expects to be called with *functions*; unless `isEmpty()` returns a function, that's probably not right. Maybe you wanted `.pipe(isEmpty)`?

Comment: Well it's not really empty is it? You start your `new BehaviorSubject<string[]>([]);` with an empty array, so it's not empty, it has a value.

Comment: isEmpty is imported from rxjs/operators. I'm not quite sure how to use it.

Comment: @rainmak3r, true. Any idea how to generate the empty$ observable ?

Comment: `I'm not quite sure how ot use it` => then use my way : `.pipe(filter(res => !!res && res.length))`

Comment: @trichetriche, thanks. I never used the ! operator like this.

Comment: Technically you don't even need it, it's just not to confuse newcomers over truthy and falsy values. Try it without, it will work the same !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misinterpreted the use of `isEmpty()`. This checks if the observable has any stream. If it does, it emits `false`, and `true` otherwise. A `BehaviousSubject` will always have a value, because you initialise it with the start stream value. IsEmpty will therefor always notify `false`.

To check if your array is empty you should do this:

```
this.empty$ = this.list$.pipe(
  map(list => list.length === 0) 
);
```

Comment: Thank you ! I'm new to Observables and at this point it's like rocket science.

Comment: @Wolf359 I can imagine! Had the same issue when I started with them